# Why does LaTeX or TeXMaker sometimes not align the lines properly?

Tags: line-breaking, hyphenation

Why does LaTeX or TeXMaker sometimes not align the lines properly?

[image]

There's nothing special in the markup of this text:

```
fazin paperista "Automated Hydrodynamic Shape Optimization Using
Neural Networks" (Schmitz, Besnard \& Hefazi) löytyy maininta
neuroverkoista, joten rajansiirtomenetelmäkin
```

---

If I switch " to ``, then I get:

[image]

---

Compilable code (although not exactly the same as mine, but one can see the problem using this code):

```
\documentclass[utf8,bachelor,manualbib]{gradu3}

\usepackage{palatino} % valitaan oletusfonttia hieman tyylikkäämpi fontti

\usepackage{graphicx} % tarvitaan vain, jos halutaan mukaan kuvia
\usepackage{amsmath}  % tarvitaan käytettäessä monimutkaisten matemaattisten kaavojen ja \eqref-kaavaviittauksen yhteydessä
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{url} % tarvitaan \url-komentoa varten
\usepackage{booktabs}

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathcal}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}

% Otetaan käyttöön author-date-järjestelmän mukaiset lähdeviittaukset:
\usepackage[longnamesfirst]{natbib}
% ks. gking.harvard.edu/files/natnotes2.pdf
% Vaihdetaan kirjoittajan nimen ja vuosiluvun väliseksi erottimeksi
% välilyönti (oletuserottimena on pilkku):
\bibpunct{(}{)}{;}{a}{}{,}


% HUOM! Tämän tulee olla viimeinen \usepackage koko dokumentissa!
\usepackage[bookmarksopen,bookmarksnumbered,linktocpage]{hyperref}

%\addbibresource{viite.bib}% Lähdetietokannan tiedostonimi
%http://www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/macros/latex/exptl/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-chicago/latex/biblatex-chicago.sty
%http://www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
%http://mirrors.med.harvard.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/latex/biblatex.sty
%http://ctan.mackichan.com/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/latex/biblatex2.sty
%http://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/logreq/logreq.sty
%https://github.com/Martin-Rotter/qt-survival-guide/blob/master/logreq.def

\begin{document}

Encyclopedia of Math puolestaan esittää, että niin kutsutun \textit{Pontryagin maksimiprinsiipin} seurauksena variationaaliset ongelmat, eli esimerkiksi rajansiirtomenetelmää soveltavat optimointiongelmat, redusoituvat erittäin usein reuna-arvotehtäviksi (katso miten, esimerkiksi Belenky 1998, 288). Lisäksi mainitaan, että tällaiset reuna-arvotehtävät ratkaistaan usein Newtonin menetelmällä osamääräisillä askeleilla. Newtonin menetelmä on yksinkertainen algoritmi. Toisaalta Schmitzin, Besnardin ja Hefazin paperista ``Automated Hydrodynamic Shape Optimization Using Neural Networks`` (Schmitz, Besnard \& Hefazi) löytyy maininta neuroverkoista, joten rajansiirtomenetelmäkin voi vaatia kompleksisia numeerisia algoritmeja, joilla tosin saavutetaan myös esimerkiksi nopeuseroja.

\end{document}
```

(the used template is this one https://yousource.it.jyu.fi/latex-thesis-classes/pages/Gradu3)

Comment: Maybe the language you have loaded does not have any breaking points for that case (apparently you did not switch do a different language). There is also a space lost in the output. Who knows? A minimal working example would show whats going on.

Comment: Don't forget to type the quotes correctly.

Comment: @Johannes_B Can/Should I attempt to force the alignment somehow?

Comment: @Sigur Actually switching the quotes from " to `` made the aligning almost work.

Comment: @mavavilj PLEASE provide a complete small document that shows the problem. Complete means compilable, everything from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`. Otherwise it is hard to give good advice.

Comment: The correct quotes are typeset as ``...'' (i.e., starting with to single back-quotes and ending with two single normal quotes).

Comment: Using package `csquotes` and its command `\enquote{enquoted text here}` allows you to forget what and which ticks and quotation marks to put where. The package takes care of that.